# WCF calling multiple times from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wcf, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

While I change or modify anything in data access layer, I am getting this error:

> 1. Unable to copy file "C:\bin\Debug\ajaxservice.Data.dll" to "bin\Debug\ajaxservice.Data.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\ajaxservice.Data.dll' because it is being used by another process. ajaxservice.Services
> 2. Unable to copy file "C:\bin\Debug\ajaxservice.Business.dll" to "bin\Debug\ajaxservice.Business.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\ajaxservice.Business.dll' because it is being used by another process. ajaxservice.Services

After I restart the system the error will not be occur again but I now I have the problem of the method getting called twice. I am calling some WCF method from JavaScript and some directly from C#. The method is being called multiple from JavaScript. If I call from C#,  the same method is working fine.

Please help me in fixing this.

```
var service = new Hotal.Services.IMenuSearchService();
service.FindRestaurant(City, Area, onRestaurantSeachSuccess, onRestaurantSeachFailed, null);
```

The method below is being called twice:

```
public IEnumerable FindRestaurant(string City, string Area)
{
    Business.Menu menu = new Business.Menu();
    return menu.FindRestaurant(City, Area);
}
public IEnumerable FindRestaurant(string City, string Area)
{
    // Linq query here
}
```

Comment: Abbas, your edit undid the formatting of the two error messages at the top.  Now we have to scroll way over to the right again.  They aren't code.

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly you expect your code to do. Why do you have 2 different `FindRestaurant` methods with the same signature?